# Is the conditional likelihood of a sample of $(X,Y)$ a conditional joint distribution of all $Y$ on all $X$'s?

Tags: conditional-probability, likelihood

Given random variables from a random sample  $(X_1,Y_1),\dots,(X_n,Y_n)$, the conditional likelihood of observing $y_i |x_i$ (for all $i$) given parameters $\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n$ is usually written as something along the lines of $L(y|x;\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n)$. Is it correct to view the conditional likelihood of the entire sample as $f(y_1,\dots,y_n|x_1,\dots,x_n,\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n)$, where $f$ is a conditional probability density function? If $Y_i$ and $Y_j$ ($i \neq j$) is conditionally independent given $X_1,\dots,X_n$, then I assume the joint distribution can be broken down to equal $\Pi f(y_i|x_1,\dots,x_n,\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n)$? Most notations I see don't explicitly denote conditioning of $Y_i$ on all $X$'s, only on $X_i$.

Answer (score 0):

As you point out, $f(y_1, ..., y_n | x_1, ..., x_n; \theta_1, ..., \theta_n)$ is valid for the most general case.

When $y_j$ are independent,
$$
f(y_1, ..., y_n |
    x_1, ..., x_n; \theta_1, ..., \theta_n)
= \Pi f(y_i| x_1, ..., x_n; \theta_1, ..., \theta_n).
$$
You say you "assume it". You can easily prove it by iteratively applying the following:
$$
f(y_1, ..., y_n |
    x_1, ..., x_n; \theta_1, ..., \theta_n)
\\= f(y_1| x_1, ..., x_n; \theta_1, ..., \theta_n)
f(y_2, ..., y_n | y_1, x_1, ..., x_n; \theta_1, ..., \theta_n)
\\= f(y_1| x_1, ..., x_n; \theta_1, ..., \theta_n)
f(y_2, ..., y_n | x_1, ..., x_n; \theta_1, ..., \theta_n).
$$
The first step is the law of conditional probability. The last step follows from the independence of $y_j$ on $y_i$, $i \neq j$.

In many problems of the literature, I guess that $y_i$ only depends on $x_i$. Hence the notation that you mention.

Comment: independence of $y_i$ and $y_j$ doesn't mean they're independent conditioned on some other variable, say $x_i,x_j$.